# filter Items of Array by Index in Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

I have mongodb Database and I have this document structure :

```
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("2145214545ffff"),
     "arr":[a , b , c , d , e , f , g , h , i, j]
   }
```

I want to execute aggregation pipeline , which gives me this result:

```
 {
         "_id": ObjectId("2145214545ffff"),
         "arr":[a , d , g , j ]
       }
```

So what i need is kind of filtering on the array's items , which give me the 1st , 4th ,  7th and so on  items.
Thx in advanced

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) operators.

The following query will be helpful:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      arr: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $range: [
              0,
              {
                $size: "$arr"
              },
              3
            ]
          },
          as: "a",
          in: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$arr",
              "$$a"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_r7GWTfyvQv)

Comment: Hey @MoOmar, was this helpful?

Comment: Hey @ngShravil.py , this was nice,Thank you very much. Also The performance is great. I used reduce operator , it was working but slower. So map operator is nice for this use case