# How to use MongoDB aggregation to get only those records whose index is divisible by 5?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is what my data looks like in a collection named usages:

```
{ _id: AUTOGENERATED_MONGO_OBJECT_ID, timeStamp: 1675122960, usage: null, limit: 2.7 },
{ _id: AUTOGENERATED_MONGO_OBJECT_ID, timeStamp: 1675123020, usage: 2.74, limit: 2.7 },
{ _id: AUTOGENERATED_MONGO_OBJECT_ID, timeStamp: 1675123080, usage: 2.62, limit: 2.7 },
{ _id: AUTOGENERATED_MONGO_OBJECT_ID, timeStamp: 1675123140, usage: 4.32, limit: 2.7 },
{ _id: AUTOGENERATED_MONGO_OBJECT_ID, timeStamp: 1675123200, usage: null, limit: 2.7 },
{ _id: AUTOGENERATED_MONGO_OBJECT_ID, timeStamp: 1675123260, usage: 5.38, limit: 2.7 },
{ _id: AUTOGENERATED_MONGO_OBJECT_ID, timeStamp: 1675123320, usage: 5.08, limit: 2.7 },
{ _id: AUTOGENERATED_MONGO_OBJECT_ID, timeStamp: 1675123380, usage: 1.02, limit: 2.7 },
{ _id: AUTOGENERATED_MONGO_OBJECT_ID, timeStamp: 1675123440, usage: 2.35, limit: 2.7 },
```

**Please Note:** This is just sample of how my data looks, actually, I have 40000 records.

I am trying to get last 60 records of data using this `mongoose` query:

```
  const count = await Usage.count()
  Usage.find({}).sort({ timeStamp: 1 }).skip(count - 60);
```

So far, everything is working fine.

But now, there is a requirement to get less data in the required range. Let's say output needs to have only 12 records from the last 60 records without losing much data. We will be plotting a line chart on the frontend using this data.

So, I can filter the data such that I will pick data whose index is divisible by 5.

So, here is my code:

```
    const count = await Usage.count();
    const data = await Usage
        .find({})
        .sort({ timeStamp: 1 })
        .skip(count - start)
        .exec();
    const requiredData = data.filter((item, index) => index % 5 === 0);
    console.log(requiredData);
```

The above code should work as expected, but it is very slow because I am filtering data after I get it from the database.

Ideally, I should filter the data using some query so the database should give me filtered results only.

Can someone help me to achieve that?

Here is a very similar question: [filter Items of Array by Index in Aggregation Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62201364/filter-items-of-array-by-index-in-aggregation-pipeline)

But in that question, OP wants to filter based on a particular field named `arr`. But in my case, I want to filter based on the whole collection. And I don't have much knowledge of how can I write a query using aggregate. I tried some video tutorials to learn aggregate, but it looks a bit complex, and need some more time to learn it.

Comment: Filtering 12 records out of 60 should not be slow.

Comment: Can you estimate the timestamp? Let's say, you get one document around every second, then you could add condition like `{$match: {timeStamp: {$gt: new Date(new Date()-2*60*1000)}}}` which would make a pre-filter to get data from last two Minutes.

Comment: Instead of `sort({ timeStamp: 1 }).skip(count - 60)` you could also use `sort({ timeStamp: -1 }).limit(60)`, then you don't need to count beforehand.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit 12 records out of 60 is just an example. Actual data will be in thousands. Also, $match solution will work (I guess), don't know why I was going behind aggregate :)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit using `sort by descending` and then using `limit` will reverse the order of data. That's why I am using `sort by ascending` and then `skip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $sort: { t: -1 } },
   { $limit: 60 },
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         sortBy: { t: 1 },
         output: {
            pos: { $documentNumber: {} }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { remainder: { $mod: ["$pos", 5] } } },
   { $match: { remainder: 1 } },
   { $sort: { t: 1 } },
   { $unset: ["pos", "remainder"] }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oiMljuNjUsz)

With `$setWindowFields` you could do it even more advanced, for example skip the document if difference to previous document is less than xyz.

Comment: Yup, it gives the required answer, but I don't understand the code well. Will try to understand it later as and when I get a bit of time. Thanks for the solution. :)